# Spliting byte[] to smaller byte[] and sending it

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, stream

I am trying to split byte array and just keep sending it until it has bytes left, then I wanna send it via bluetooth. Is this correct? Not sure how to make the write to work in background task/thread, so i commented that.

```
public void Write(byte[] bytes)
{
    //System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
    //{
        byte[] tmpArray = bytes.Take(10).ToArray();

        try
        {
            mmOutStream.Write(tmpArray);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error occurred when sending data", ex);
        }
    //}).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

---

Edit: The write works, but know how would I receve such data, the read method looks like this (now it only gets the whole thing):

```
public byte[] Read()
{
    byte[] temp = null;
    try
    {
        byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
        var finalByteList = new List<byte>();
        do
        {
            numberOfBytesRead = mmInStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
            finalByteList.AddRange(myReadBuffer);
        }
        while (mmInStream.IsDataAvailable());

        // here is the final array of bytes
        var finalByteArray = finalByteList.ToArray();
        temp = finalByteArray;
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Input stream was disconnected", ex);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to put it in a loop if you want to write all of the bytes.  The [Write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.write?view=netframework-4.8) method already has an overload that will take an offset and length

```
int offset = 0;
int count = 10;
int len = bytes.Length;

while (offset < len)
{
  mmOutStream.Write(bytes,offset,count);
  offset += count;
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it :) Much simpler than what I was gonna post though. Short and natively supported.

Comment: That should be `mmOutStream.Write(bytes,offset, Math.Min(count, len - offset))` otherwise it will throw if the last offset is less than 10 from the end of the buffer.

Comment: Would it be possible to use a thread or task instead of a while loop, since I want it to work in background

Comment: yes, you can run it in the background, but that does not change the need to use a loop.